# Variadic template not compiling

Tags: c++, templates, recursion, variadic-templates

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename A, typename... B>
void prints(A num, B... args){
    std::cout << num << std::endl;
    prints(args...);
}

int main(){
    prints(1,2,3);
    return 0;
}
```

When I compile, I get these errors:

```
In instantiation of 'void prints(A, B ...) [with A = int; B = {}]':
error: no matching function for call to 'prints()'

main.cpp:4:10: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
main.cpp:7:11: note:   candidate expects at least 1 argument, 0 provided
```

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow! could you give us a little more information at the top of the post? In example, how you are compiling this code? thanks

Answer (score 5):

Your function waits for 1 or more parameters:

```
template<typename A, typename... B>
void prints(A num, B... args)
```

When you invoke it with only 1 parameter, the `args...` pack is empty, so the recursive call:

```
prints(args...);
```

becomes

```
prints();
```

But your function waits for (at least) 1 argument, so can't match this call.

You need to add a zero-argument overload of `prints()` to match the empty call:

```
void prints()
{ }
```

and you have to declare it before the recursive version.

As pointed by Evg (thanks) starting from C++17 you can avoid the zero-argument overload and, using `if constexpr`, you can call the recursion only when `args...` isn't empty.

That is... starting from C++17 you can write

```
template <typename A, typename... B>
void prints (A num, B... args) {
   std::cout << num << std::endl;

   if constexpr ( sizeof...(args) > 0u )
      prints(args...);
}
```

and you don't need the zero-argument overload anymore.

Observe that if you simply write (with a simple `if`, no `if constexpr`)

```
   if ( sizeof...(args) > 0u )
      prints(args...);
```

you get (without the zero-argument overload) a compilation error because the compiler has to compile the `prints(args...)` part also when `sizeof...(args)` is zero (it's exactly `if constexpr` that avoid this).

Comment: Or `if constexpr (sizeof...(B) > 0)` in C++17.

Comment: @JeJo, good point. For simple function body with a single `std::cout << ...;` statement a fold expression looks like a better choice.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution using fold expressions is shown below:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>

template <class... TArgs>
void prints(TArgs&&... args) {
    (std::cout << ... << std::forward<TArgs>(args));
}

int main(){
    prints(1,2,3);
    return 0;
}
```