# getting type index from a type list in C++

Tags: c++, c++17, variadic-templates, if-constexpr

When I try and get the index of a type within a list of types using below, the code compiles and returns the correct value when the else clause is used. However when I skip the else clause and place the  `return getIndex<T, Ts...>(x + 1);` just after the end of the if clause the code fails to compile as it continues to unwind `getIndex<T, Ts...>` recursively resulting in the error shown below. This is the case with `gcc` and `clang`. Is this expected?

```
#include <type_traits>
template <typename T, typename U, typename ...Ts>
constexpr int getIndex(int x = 0)
{
   if constexpr(std::is_same_v<T,U>)
   {
      return x;
   }
   else
   {
      return getIndex<T, Ts...>(x + 1);
   }
}

int main()
{
   return getIndex<int, float, double, int, char>();
}
```

Error when moving return outside of else

```
getI.cc: In instantiation of ‘int getIndex(int) [with T = int; U = char; Ts = {}]’:
getI.cc:9:32:   recursively required from ‘int getIndex(int) [with T = int; U = double; Ts = {int, char}]’
getI.cc:9:32:   required from ‘int getIndex(int) [with T = int; U = float; Ts = {double, int, char}]’
getI.cc:14:51:   required from here
getI.cc:9:32: error: no matching function for call to ‘getIndex<int>(int)’
    9 |       return getIndex<T, Ts...>(x + 1);
      |              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~
getI.cc:3:5: note: candidate: ‘template<class T, class U, class ... Ts> int getIndex(int)’
    3 | int getIndex(int x = 0)
      |     ^~~~~~~~
getI.cc:3:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
getI.cc:9:32: note:   couldn’t deduce template parameter ‘U’
    9 |       return getIndex<T, Ts...>(x + 1);
      |              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~
```

Answer (score 3):

Peter Taran's answer has already touched on why the code compiles with the `else` clause, but he didn't really touch on why the compilation error occurs or how to fix it.  Here is a working version of your code:

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T>
constexpr int getIndex(int x = 0)
{
   return -1;
}

template <typename T, typename U, typename ...Ts>
constexpr int getIndex(int x = 0)
{
   if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T,U>)
   {
      return x + 1;// NOTE: you have a bug on this line
   }
   else
   {
      return getIndex<T, Ts...>(x + 1);
   }
}

int main()
{
   constexpr int index = getIndex<int, float, double, int, char>();

   return 0;
}
```

Admittedly, I haven't used variadic templates much, but from what I am understanding here, the main problem is in this snippet of your compilation errors:

```
getI.cc:9:32: error: no matching function for call to ‘getIndex<int>(int)’
```

Despite having a base case defined in your recursive template, it seems like variadic templates are required to fully unpack.  Because of that, you need a `getIndex<T>` defined, even if the code is not reached in your example.  Adding the single argument `getIndex<T>` allowed the code to compile and run.

EDIT: [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62822810/variadic-template-not-compiling?rq=1) is also related, a good read, and is also another possible solution to your issue.

Answer (score 2):

As I realized, broken code is:

```cpp
template <typename T, typename U, typename ...Ts>
constexpr int getIndex(int x = 0)
{
   if constexpr(std::is_same_v<T,U>) {
      return x;
   }
   return getIndex<T, Ts...>(x + 1);
}
```

Accoring to this [article](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if):

> In a constexpr if statement, the value of condition must be an
> expression contextually converted to bool, where the conversion is a
> constant expression. If the value is true, then statement-false is
> discarded (if present), otherwise, statement-true is discarded.

Note that nothing is said about discarding statements outside if-else clause, so you should expect that recusive `getIndex`'s will be instantiated.